# error when requesting xml document as xml via web api call

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have an xml document that I want to return via a web api call.

I want to allow the user the option of the response via content negotiation.

```
 [HttpGet]
 public HttpResponseMessage Get()
 {
      var doc = new XmlDocument();
      doc.LoadXml("<MyExport SomeProperty='Some Value'></MyExport>");

      return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, doc);
  }
```

When I request this an Accept header of application/xml I get the error:

```
<Error>
    <Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
    <ExceptionMessage>The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'.</ExceptionMessage>
    <ExceptionType>System.InvalidOperationException</ExceptionType>
```

What am I doing wrong I thought this should be handled via content negotiation?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are returning XML (or, more accurately, an XmlDocument object)---so are pre-empting any sensible content negotiation. If the client asks for JSON, but the server returns XML, there's going to be a problem.

The idea with Web API is that you return POCO objects and the framework serializes them automagically into the requested format.